# Continuous onto function from $(\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q)\cap [0,1]\to \Bbb Q\cap [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Does there exist a continuous onto function from :

1. $(\Bbb Q)\cap [0,1]\to  \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q\cap [0,1]$?
2. $(\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q)\cap [0,1]\to  \Bbb Q\cap [0,1]$?

(1)  is false because $(\Bbb Q)\cap [0,1]$  is countable whereas $
\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q\cap [0,1]$
 is not and image of a countable set is countable.

(2) .I don't know about this.Please give some hints on this question.I am clueless here.

**EDIT**:In the question given as **duplicate**,I am unable to understand how to map each irrational number to a rational number.Please give some details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $f:(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})\cap [0,1]\to \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$. Prove there exists a continuous$f$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935102/let-f-mathbbr-setminus-mathbbq-cap-0-1-to-mathbbq-cap-0-1-prove)

Comment: How did you get the duplicate,I couldn't@Mark

Comment: Do you mean how did I find it?  It was the 7th link down under "related" for me.  Or do you want an explaination of how the duplicate solves the question?

Comment: No I meant in the answer provided ,how to properly define that function

Comment: Also a [possible duplicate of this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506057/continuous-onto-function-from-irrationals-in-0-1-onto-rationals-in-0-1).  That answer has a much better construction than the first I linked.

Comment: [All good things come in three.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1816999)